# How to output data from iSQL to csv file with column names

Tags: csv, sybase, siebel, isql

I am trying to query a Sybase using iSQL client and export the query results to a text file or CSV file with column name. However the column headings are not exported to the file. I tried below script it shows error message, below the working script without column heading and error script, appreciate any valuable advice.

**working sql:**

```
select * from siebel.S_ORG_EXT;  
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\Siebel SQLs\\Account.CSV' FORMAT TEXT 
DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE ''
```

**Not working  sql :**

```
select * from siebel.S_ORG_EXT;  
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\Siebel SQLs\\Account.CSV' FORMAT TEXT 
DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '' WITH COLUMN NAMES;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sybase iAnywhere the `WITH COLUMN NAMES` option is not recognized by that Sybase product.  Just thought I'd mention this for those like myself who have struggled with a similar issue.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM siebel.S_ORG_EXT; OUTPUT TO 'C:\\Siebel SQLs\\Account.CSV' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '' WITH COLUMN NAMES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a different SQL client. For example [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) which supports JDBC connections. In other SQL clients you will need to import the jconn2.jar which is part of your local web client installation.